# Focus going out of the popup page to the parent page

Tags: javascript, css

I have a popup page loading on signin button click. The problem is when I keep pressing tabs, the focus is going out to the parent page. I want the focus to keep looping on the popup on tab press until it is closed

http://jsfiddle.net/2EXL5/

HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="Css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.bpopup.min.js"></script>
    <link href="Css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row header">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img src="Css/Images/Logo.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8 quickbuttons">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" tabindex="1" id="btnSignin"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign in</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" tabindex="2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> Help</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <h3 style="margin-top:50px;">Signup</h3>
                <form class="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="txtFirstName">First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="First Name" value="" id="txtFirstName" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" required="" tabindex="3" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="txtLastName">Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="Last Name" value="" id="txtLastName" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" required="" tabindex="4" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="txtEmailId">Email Id</label>
                        <input type="email" name="Email ID" value="" id="txtEmailId" class="form-control" placeholder="example@yahoo.com" required="" tabindex="5" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="txtPassword">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="Password" value="" id="txtPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="" tabindex="6" />
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" tabindex="7" id="btnSingUp"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Sign Up</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="element_to_pop_up">
            <a class="b-close">
                X
                <br />
            </a>
            <h3>Login</h3>
            <form class="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="txtLoginEmailId">Email Id</label>
                    <input type="email" name="Email ID" value="" id="txtLoginEmailId" class="form-control" placeholder="example@yahoo.com" required="" tabindex="1" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="txtLoginPassword">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="Password" value="" id="txtLoginPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="" tabindex="2" />
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" tabindex="3"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Sign In</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $("#btnSignin").click(function () {
            $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using jquery capture the tab and when it is about to leave from last element of child page stop propagatation and preventdefault and give focus to first element in child page

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the focusOut event of the last focusable item in the popup and when that happens just send the focus to the first focusable element in your pop-up.

You can see it working in this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2EXL5/4/) (needs setting tabindexes right).

I added an ID to the button to find it easily and then just add this to the click function:

```
$('#signin-button').focusout(function() {$(this).closest('form').find('input').first().focus();});
```